# Grammar of tikz \path command

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-path

This is one of the more confusing things regarding `tikz`. You can find various usage examples for the `\path` or `\draw` commands online and each of those will be unique in its own way. I wonder if there is a Backus–Naur form (BNF) grammar available for these commands that shows how the arguments should be passed.

Comment: There is no BNF grammar for anything TeX-related, because [TeX is not context-free](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4201).

Comment: @HenriMenke Interesting point, what would be the alternative then?

Comment: @DarthPaghius The alternative is the _documentation_ (as the excellent pgfmanual).

Comment: @PaulGaborit Almost no modern programming language is context-free but does it prevent you from having a BNF for a specific subset of their syntax? No. You assume a set of rules (no macros, etc) and write a BNF or something similar which gives you a compact representation of some otherwise complicated syntax which would take a dozen pages to document. Anyway I don't think what I want readily exists so maybe I should try and create one myself.

Comment: Can you give a couple of examples that threw you off?

Comment: @DarthPaghius The problem with formulating a grammar for TeX is the existance and importance of catcodes.  Basically everything can be used to delimit everything.  Not even the primitives are fixed, just make any character active and assign the primitive to it.  On top you also have different modes where catcodes can be different.  That said, the pgfmanual already presents the syntax in a form similar to a grammar, e.g. the `\path` command is presented as `\path <specification>`.

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153912/is-it-possible-to-produce-a-context-free-grammar-for-tikz-path-node