# Tikz language syntax

Tags: tikz-pgf, editors, programming

I'm hoping to add a tikz-specific language environment to my LaTeX editor (vscode), I've run into a bit of an issue looking for any speicifications for tikz grammar though.

Would anybody know of any pre-existing tikz language grammars, or useful information? I don't feel I know enough to just work it out.

To clairfy I'm not looking for robust syntax error detection as in [Is it possible to produce a context free grammar for Tikz path? node?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153912/is-it-possible-to-produce-a-context-free-grammar-for-tikz-path-node). The end goal here is syntax highlighting and autocompletion.

Thanks,

tecosaur.

Comment: @Henri Menke I've seen that, but it doesn't help. The answer mostly covers determining whether something is a syntax error, which I am not concerned with.
It's along similar lines, however a fleshed out version of marczellm's comment would be the sort of thing I'm looking for — and I have not been able to find anything like that.

Comment: Do you mean this kind of thing ? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=torn4dom4n.latex-support or more likely https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=James-Yu.latex-workshop

Comment: Not quite. Since there's a lot of tikz-specific stuff such as `\draw (0,0) circle (1)` it would be nice to have enhanced handling of that.

Comment: In Atom editor, there is a `Language Latex2e` package which handles a tikz grammar, but I it doesn't seem as specific as what you need. Maybe ask the guys developping LateX Workshop for vscode (raise an issue or something)

Comment: I am one of the guys working on it :P the issue isn't on the coding side, it's on the working out what needs to be coded. Hence why I'm here instead of GitHub.

Comment: @tecosaur The syntax for TikZ path specifications is described in the manual in section 14 »Syntax for Path Specifications«.  The answer I had initially marked as duplicate explains why not such specification can ever be complete.